Semisimplicity of induced representation of a irreducible representation
This question occurs when I read this one.
Suppose $k$ is a field of char $0$ (not necessarily complex numbers, in my case it's $\mathbb Q_p$), and $G$ is a profinite group (in my case, $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$), and $H$ is an open subgroup, not necessarily normal. Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional irreducible $k$-representation of $H$, then I want to ask whether $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G(V)$ is semisimple?
In the link above, it's true when $H$ is normal , but I want to remove this condition in char $0$ case, and without normalness, $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G(V)$ as a $H$-representation will no longer be a direct sum of copies of $V$, which is why the argument there fails.
Any help would be fine.

As $H$ is open, it has finite index, hence contains a finite index subgroup $N$, which is normal in $G$. Then the $H$-induced representation sits inside an $N$-induced representation which is semisimple.

Good point. Thanks.
